# Removing child from panel, bound to an ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a drag and drop functionality for a couple of buttons which are contained in an `ObservableCollection<>` in the view model, the collection is later used as an `ItemsSource` for a `StackPanel`:

This is the xaml structure:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="RingHolder" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Rings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <customControls:RingsStackpanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <customControls:RingControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="50"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Where `RingsStackPanel` inherits from `StackPanel` and `RingControl` inherits from `Button`.

In order to allow the button to be dragged around freely I want to detach it from it's parent like so:

```
if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) is ContentPresenter contentPresenter)
{
    if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(contentPresenter) is RingsStackpanel ringStackPanel)
    {
        ringStackPanel.Children.Remove(contentPresenter);
    }
}
```

However I get the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException:
>
> Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel

Which makes sense, I can only modify it by modifying the `ItemsSource` that is bound to it, however in this scenario, removing an item from the `ObservableCollection<>` causes the selected `Button` to disappear as it's being destroyed. Is there anyway I can allow my `Button` to move around freely, without creating a clone of it (this would be nigh impossible as the project currently is).

Comment: What objects does the `Rings` collection contain? What should happen when you drop your button somewhere?

Comment: @dymanoid I don't believe that this information is relevant for the sake of this question, the collection contains ViewModels, from which I am unable to generate a new `RingControl`, so it has to be the one already created and visible, when I drop the button I will assign it to a different collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the data item from the source collection and add a public method to your `RingsStackpanel` class that removes the visual from the logical tree:

```
public class RingsStackpanel : StackPanel
{
    ...
    public void RemoveElement(Visual visual) => RemoveVisualChild(visual);
}
```

You should then be able to handle the `Unloaded` event of the `ContentPresenter` and remove its parent-child with the `StackPanel`. Something like this:

```
if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) is ContentPresenter contentPresenter)
{
    if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(contentPresenter) is RingsStackpanel ringStackPanel
        && RingHolder.ItemsSource is ObservableCollection<YourItemType> dataItems
        && contentPresenter.DataContext is YourItemType dataItem)
    {
        //wait for the ContentPresenter to get unloaded
        RoutedEventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (ss, ee) =>
        {
            //remove the parent-child relationship:
            ringStackPanel.RemoveElement(contentPresenter);

            contentPresenter.Unloaded -= handler;
        };
        //remove the data object
        dataItems.Remove(dataItem);
    }
}
```